# placeholder text asterisks differs than normal asterisks

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set asterisks in placeholder exactly as div asterisks but div asterisks has six pointed stars and placeholder asterisks has five pointed stars.

```css
*{
  font-size: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="*****" /><!--It's five pointed stars-->
<div>*****</div><!--It's six pointed stars-->
```

I also tried like `placeholder="&#x2a;&#x2a;&#x2a;&#x2a;&#x2a;"` but also it appears five pointed stars.

Comment: Different fonts are applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to normalize  the `font-family` for one which renders six pointed asterisks (e.g. `serif`). The issue you see is because your `input` and `body` are using different default font sets.

```css
body,
input {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: serif;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="*****" />
<div>*****</div>
```

Comment: Ooops! I was trying to set Arial.